# Submitted form data visible in url despite using method=post

Tags: java, jsp, http, url, post

I have used POST as the method when submitting form data (namely textarea), but it is still visible in the URL. This is causing the following error in my web application (running on NetBeans):

```
Aug 30, 2016 11:25:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.fill(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:574)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:217)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:996)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is caused due to the limit exceeded in the URL (from what I have gathered).

**index.jsp** (code fragment):

```
form id="maryWebClient" action="preprocess" method="POST">
```

I have also later tried to explicitly set the method as POST by using the following code in **Preprocessor.java**, to which data is being sent by using urlPatterns from index.jsp (code fragment):

```
URL obj=new URL("http://..../process?INPUT_TEXT="+"\""+   URLEncoder.encode(sent)+"\""+          "&INPUT_TYPE=TEXT&OUTPUT_TYPE=REALISED_DURATIONS&LOCALE=hi_IN&OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMS=phone+stressed+accented");
BufferedReader bfr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(obj.openStream(),"utf8"));
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach solved my problem. I have used ajax call to send a post request.

```
var postData=$("#maryWebClient").serializeArray();

 $.ajax({
     url: "preprocess",
     context:this,
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"json",
     data:postData,

     success: function(response){
         $("#INPUT_TEXT").val(response["x"]);
         $("#INPUT_TEXT2").val(response["y"]);
     },
             error: function(errorData){alert(errorData);}
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

In a GET request, the parameters are sent as part of the URL.

In a POST request, the parameters are sent as a body of the request, after the headers.

To do a POST with HttpURLConnection, you need to write the parameters to the connection after you have opened the connection.

This code should get you started:

```
String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
int    postDataLength = postData.length;
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL    url            = new URL( request );
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Jenkin. I did try something similar to this mentioned in this link [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/). But it has not worked for me. I also tried your code, but am getting the same error.

Comment: I am confused as to why the jsp/HTML form `POST` is being routed through a `servlet`?

Comment: @Scary I was focusing on how to send POST data with java URL class, rest approach is depend on OP's point of view, I cant understand downvote related this